# Instances using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I have class with 2 properties. The one is a `List<double>` and the other one is a `Queue<double>`. I only have the `Type` information during runtime. I need to instantiate and populate both the properties. Is there a generic way of doing this? I have created a method that will create an `IEnumerable` because that is a common interface for both of these. However, now I'm stuck with an `IEnumerable` and I don't know how to cast to something useful to `Add` or `Enqueue` based on `Type`.

Comment: Type information about the object these properties are in? Have you tried to instantiate the object at runtime?

Comment: Could you explain, please, what is this `Type` information about? With what do you want to populate those properties?

Comment: Type information from reflection. So in this case if you did typeof(List<double>), that is what I have to work with. When I only have that information, how can I instantiate a new List<double> and then also add items to it.

Comment: How about [Activator.CreateInstance()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2)? You can pass the type and it will create an instance of specified type.

Comment: That returns an object, I need to be able to add items to a list or queue, which means casting but I dont know how to cast when I just have runtime type information

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
dynamic collection = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<double>));
        if (collection.GetType() == typeof(Queue<double>))
        {
            collection.Enqueue(1);
        }
        else if(collection.GetType() == typeof(List<double>))
        {
            collection.Add(1);
        }
```

and instead of `typeof(List<double>)` you insert your type variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If you can imagine some JSON `{arr: [1,2,3]}` and that needs to get deserialized into a class. This json array can get deserialized into a lot of different structures. You might have a class with prop `public List<double> Arr {get;set;}` but I might have `public Queue<int> Arr {get;set;}` and someone else might have `Stack<decimal>`. I need to be able to cater for all/most scenarios. This solution unfortunately cannot scale.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your issue is. But (to me) it sounds like you want a container class to manage two different data structures.

```
class MyContainerClass<T> : IContainer
{
    private List<T> list;
    private Queue<T> queue ;

    public MyContainerClass(){
        list = new List<T>();
        queue = new Queue<T>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(T value){
        //Logic for handling add
        list.Add(value);
        queue.Enqueue(value);
    }


    public virtual void Remove(T value)
    {
        //Logic for handling remove
    }

    //Etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If you can imagine some JSON `{arr: [1,2,3]}` and that needs to get deserialized into a class. This json array can get deserialized into a lot of different structures. You might have a class with prop `public List<double> Arr {get;set;}` but I might have `public Queue<int> Arr {get;set;}` and someone else might have `Stack<decimal>`. I need to be able to cater for all/most scenarios.

Comment: If all values are numeric, then look into using the data type `double` as the base type you deserialise to, from which you can convert into `List<int>` or `List<decimal>` using ConvertAll.....

Like So :
`new List<double> { 1,2,3 }.ConvertAll<int>(x => (int)x)`